# How can I load the Caret library with R version 3.5.1?

Tags: r, package, r-caret

I need to use the createDataPartition function in Caret and I cannot load the Caret library properly in version 3.5.1. What can I do?

> library(caret)
>   Loading required package: lattice
>   Loading required package: ggplot2
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>   there is no package called ‘Biobase’
>
> install.packages("Biobase")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Xavier Roca/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘Biobase’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biobase")
```

Then try to load or install `caret`.

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-can-t-install-package-caret-in-rstudio-cloud/9880/5?u=max for background